# Column-based Ordering in Dijit Dropdown

Tags: jsp, dojo, dijit.form

I have a dijit.form.FilteringSelect widget on a JSP page that displays numbers from 120 to 0. The client has expressed that they do not want a number spinner or text input (on its own) or anything efficient like that. What they want is the FilteringSelect to display all the numbers in a column-based order, with 120 through 111 showing in column 1, 110 to 101 in column 2, and so on.

But, the natural behavior of FilteringSelect is to add options in a row until it "fills up" and then wrap around to the next row. How many elements it takes to "fill up" a row seems to vary with the browser (in particular, IE 11) even with an explicitly set width. My first idea of adding elements in an order that makes the widget look column-sorted (120, 110, 100, ...) failed for that reason, at least with tests using the problematic browsers.

Is there a property, method, or style that I can apply to the widget to force elements to be column-ordered, assuming that I know how many columns and/or rows I want?

My code:

```
<select name="a" id="a" onchange="update()"/>"
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect"
    data-dojo-property="autoComplete:true, width: '150px;'">
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="120">
        <c:set var="j" value="${120 - i}" />
        <option value="${j}">${j}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: you can try.  .dijitComboBoxMenu {
columns:10px 4;
-webkit-columns:10px 4; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-columns:10px 4; /* Firefox */
} does not work on older browsers though

Comment: I should mention we need to support (at least) IE 8 through 11, Firefox, and Chrome.